# How to append new data in googlesheet

Tags: r, google-sheets, dataset

I have a below mentioned dataframe in R which I'm fetching from database using RMySQL on interval of 3 hours.

Query:

```
Select Form_No, Date, Name, Age from Test where Date(Date)>='2020-12-01';
```

DF:

```
Form_No      Date                  Name            Age
POS-1        2020-12-01 10:16:12   Alex            29
POS-2        2020-12-01 10:18:34   Mike            31
POS-3        2020-12-01 14:16:22   Paul            21
POS-4        2020-12-01 18:33:14   John            27
POS-5        2020-12-01 20:13:34   Cohe            45
```

It is oblivious that after every 3 hours when I run the script there are some additional entries might have created in dataframe and when I use the below-mentioned code to upload the data in googlesheet it override the previous information and update the new data.

The Problem is that for each rows there are some observations might have captured by the reviewer of the information.

The Code I am using is:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(stringr)
    library(RMySQL)
    library(googlesheets)
    
    connection<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user='User', password='Password', 
                     dbname='Db name',
                     host='host info')
    
    Query<- paste0("Select Form_No, Date, Name, Age from Test where Date(Date)>='2020-12-01';")
    DF <- dbGetQuery(connection,Query)
    
    setwd("/home/path")
    write.csv(x = DF, file = "cust_data.csv", row.names = FALSE)

as<-gs_title("TargetSheet")
gs_upload("cust_data.csv", sheet_title = "TargetSheet", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I want to keep the sequence of Form_No and every details same while uploading the new batch of information.

For Example, If I had run the query at 06:00 AM and there were five entry as shown in DF and all of them uploaded to google sheet, now if I run the script at 09:00 am then in my query there is possibility that along with those five entry there are some more entries.

I need to append those extra entries in google sheet now except for the five entries which are already uploaded last time.

Comment: If you share a sample copy of your sheet, using the following guide, with the minimal amount of data needed to demonstrate the issue, and hand enter your desired result, we should be able to help you.  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en  It sounds like you are trying to keep in sync dynamic data, from formulas, and static data, entered manually, which can be tricky, but possible.